# A problem in model theory: For each m and n indicate how to write down a sentence...

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Recently I am working on my course Computability and Logic by Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey. I have some confusion on the conception of model and thus I cannot finish my homework well, and there is an exercise described like this:

"For each m and n indicate how to write down a sentence $D_(mn)$ (mn stands for the subscript for D) that is true in a model of Eq if and only if there are at least m equivalence classes with exactly n elements. " (Eq means the equivalence relation, a model of a set of sentences is any interpretation in which all sentences in the set are true)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFd0N.png)

I do not know how to prove it, maybe I shall express $D_(mn)$ specifically? Can anyone give me a hint or a proof of this problem?

Comment: Use the results of previous Ex.12.10

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA : Thank you for giving me a hint, but I still do not understand how to use Ex.12.10 solve 12.11. Does it mean I should find out a instance to prove this problem?

Comment: You need to show that for any $m, n$ there is a sentence $D_{m, n}$ expressing this. Think about it for $m = 2, n = 3$. $D_{m, n}$ will say, There are at least n things that are not equivalent, and each of them is equivalent to exactly n things.